# Extracting Latitude and longitude in imacros

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I just started with imacros and have a query, like how do I extract Latitude and longitude from a `<a>` tag

```
<div class="iconMap" onclick="stopPage=true;">
<a class='stop-propagation' href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&longt=73.1290596&projectOrProp=Project&city=Thane&includeJs=y&type=poiMap2017&address=Thane, Maharashtra" id="map_link_27774907" onclick="stopPage=true; showPhotoMap('/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&longt=73.1290596&projectOrProp=Project&city=Thane&includeJs=y&type=poiMap2017&address=Thane, Maharashtra');"><span class="icoMap"></span>Map</a>
</div>
```

I want to extract `lat=19.2412011 longt=73.1290596`

This is what I have tried

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

But I get the text as **Map**
Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to change the` attr` from class to `data-link&&txt`

Comment: Used This "TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:data-link&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT"........ but this also doesn't work.

Comment: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=DATA-LINK:data-link&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT` can you please try this

Comment: Tried...........No sucess yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will be more successful:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM

SET lat EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\?(lat=.+?)&/)[1];")
SET longt EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/&(longt=.+?)&/)[1];")
PROMPT "{{lat}} {{longt}}"
```

Comment: your code gives me this ...."<a class="stop-propagation" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2208218&amp;longt=73.1303537&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra" id="map_link_24530201" onclick="stopPage=true; showPhotoMap('/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2208218&amp;longt=73.1303537&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra');" style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><span class="icoMap"></span>Map</a>"

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got the above problem solved, This is the working code

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=class:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET lat EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\?(lat=.+?)&/)[1];")
SET longt EVAL("var regex = /longt=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/g; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")

PROMPT "{{lat}} {{longt}}"
```

Thanks.